# Intent to launch a website from activity doesn't work after 2-3 times

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a webview activity and button to open a website in default browser after user clicks on
show more button.I destoy the webview activity after launching the browser intent as shown in the code below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(intent);
 finish()
```

My problem is,
i) After launching 2-3 websites using the intent it stops loading the website in the browser

ii) Sometimes it launches the browser on click of button but loads previous url which was opened in the browser.

iii)I tried setting Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP for intent but it does not help.

Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I found the issue but no solution yet. When you have FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED set for the window, browser intent behaves differently. Any work around this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Found those who comes looking back at this question,I found a work around listen to ACTION_USER_PRESENT intent and launch the browser everything works great.